# Displaying the first category from a custom taxonomy with get_the_terms

Tags: custom-post-types

I have setup a custom post type with a custom taxonomy as categories.

I need to use [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) or [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) to return the first category of a post in the custom post type.

But I can't quite figure out how to use it in comparison to [`get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/).

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is an example i have used :

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

  $category = get_the_terms( $id, 'event_category' );
  //get First Category
  $firstCategory = $category[0];
  //get category link
    $category_link = get_category_link($firstCategory->term_id);
    //echo category name
    echo $firstCategory->name;

 endwhile;
?>
```

change event_category with your taxonomy slug

Comment: You are welcome , vote my my answer if it was helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one please:

`$terms = get_the_terms();
$term = reset($terms);`